How to update a collection inside a struct in rust?
Probably this question already has been asked, maybe with different wording, but I couldn't find it. If this gets closed due to this, apologies, but I did try before.
In fact, the problem is simple:
use std::collections::BTreeSet;

pub struct Service {
    blobs: BTreeSet<u16>,
}

impl Service {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let bt: BTreeSet<u16> = BTreeSet::new();
        Self { blobs: bt }
    }

    fn insert(&self, val: u16) -> bool {
        &self.blobs.insert(val);
        true
    }
    fn print(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.blobs.len());
    }
}
fn main() {
    let s: Service = Service::new();
    s.print();
    s.insert(4);
    s.print();
}

When compiling this, I get:
`self` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable

What I understand here, is that actually, I can't just update the treeset, as it's immutable.
So I tried with
pub struct Service {
    blobs: &'static mut BTreeSet<u16>,
}

and
  fn new() -> Self {
        let bt: &mut BTreeSet<u16> = &mut BTreeSet::new();
        Self { blobs: bt }
    }

but that yields
creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use
(while the original error is still there, so now I have two...)
I understand I should somehow make the BTreeSet mutable, but how?

Why can't you use &mut self in insert()?

@ChayimFriedman good question - I don't know? I mean, it even didn't occur to me. Coming from other languages, the thinking is that I need to change the member in the object, that marking the whole object as mutable is even possible is like mind blown to me and something of a paradigm change...

you just say "insert need the object to be mut". Not all method need a mutable self.

Most of the time the error message just tell you how to fix the code, all hail rust compiler.
PS *******************> cargo run --bin mess_around
   Compiling mess_around v0.1.0 (*******************)
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `self.blobs` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
  --> mess_around\src/main.rs:14:9
   |
14 |         self.blobs.insert(val)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^ `self` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable
   |
help: consider changing this to be a mutable reference
   |
13 |     fn insert(&mut self, val: u16) -> bool {
   |               ~~~~~~~~~

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0596`.
error: could not compile `mess_around` (bin "mess_around") due to 1 previous error

Fixed
use std::collections::BTreeSet;

pub struct Service {
    blobs: BTreeSet<u16>,
}

impl Service {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let bt: BTreeSet<u16> = BTreeSet::new();
        Self { blobs: bt }
    }

    fn insert(&mut self, val: u16) -> bool {
        self.blobs.insert(val)
    }
    fn print(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.blobs.len());
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut s: Service = Service::new();
    s.print();
    s.insert(4);
    s.print();
}

